# Count the repeated 1s in a binary sequence - r

Tags: arrays, r

Let us consider a binary sequence like the following

```
00001001110000011000000111111
```

I would like to count the repeated 1s in the sequence, as follows

```
00001001230000012000000123456
```

I was thinking of the following solution

```
> b<-c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1)
> rle(b)
  Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:8] 4 1 2 3 5 2 6 6
  values : num [1:8] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

but the result in "lengths" and "num" do not apply to my case.

Comment: Is it a string or vector of numbers as in 'b'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can either use the built-in function `rleid` from `data.table` to use as a grouping variable in `ave`, get the sequence and multiply with 'b' so that any value that is 0 will be 0 after the multiplication

```
library(data.table)
ave(b, rleid(b), FUN = seq_along)*b
#[1] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

---

Or using `rle` from `base R`, we create a group by replicating the sequence of 'values' with the 'lengths' and then use it in `ave` as before

```
grp <- with(rle(b), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))
ave(b, grp, FUN = seq_along)*b
#[1] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: Given that you use `data.table`, another possibility would be `rowid(rleid(b))*b`